# How to use plugin on generated html

Tags: jquery, html

I want to apply my jQuery to html that will be generated by jQuery before. I know how to apply events to jQuery if they were added/generated by the script:

Normal:

```
$("selector").click(handler);
```

Added/generated:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'selector', handler);
```

But I also use plug ins with their own orders like:

```
$("selector").blaplugin();
```

How do I apply those plugins to my document (or rather the body of the document) if it was generated?

Comment: You can'd to much, after the html is added you need to manually select the elements and initialize the plugin